# Loading two different versions of the same shared library

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

I'm in a situation that's quite similar to the following. There's `libA.so` that depending on some compile time flags exhibits slightly different behaviour (it's an external lib, and I can't modify the source). Then, I have `libB.so` that depends on `libA.so` (compiled with say `-DVALUE=1`), and in my executable I depend both on `libB.so`, as well as on `libA.so`, but compiled with `-DVALUE=0`. However, once I launch it, ld resolves all symbols with one of `libA.so` versions, so both my executable and `libB.so` are using the same functions.

Is there any way to specify that I want to load resolve undefined symbols of `libB.so` only using its dependencies? I've tried using `-Wl,-Bgroup` flag when building `libB.so`, but it didn't change anything. I know there's `dlmopen` that can load the library in a new namespace, but I'd like to have it loaded automatically at startup.

I'm attaching a set of files that reproduce the behaviour:

libA.so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _STR(x) #x
#define STR(x) _STR(x)

#ifndef VALUE
#define VALUE default
#endif

void func2() {
    printf(STR(VALUE) "\n");
}

void func() {
    func2();
}
```

libB.so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void func(void);

void b_func() {
    func();
}
```

executable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void b_func(void);
extern void func(void);

int main() {
    func();    // should print "default"
    b_func();  // should print "other"
}
```

build commands:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared A.c -o libA.so
gcc -fPIC -shared -DVALUE=other A.c -o libA2.so
gcc -fPIC -shared B.c -L. -lA2 -o libB.so
gcc main.c -L. -lA -lB -o main
```

Curiously, it all works fine on OS X.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to achieve this without resorting to dlsym or dlmopen.