# Linking JNI code with the JVM

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Essentially, the question is this. I have a Java program from which I load a JNI library. Can that JNI library be linked to HotSpot's `libjvm.so` shared library, and accordingly call functions unique to HotSpot - that is, outside of `jni.h`?

When I try and do so in a straightforward way, the result is the program crashing with:

`java: symbol lookup error: /path/to/libtest.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK7oopDesc5klassEv`

This gives the appearance of failing to load because it can't resolve the HotSpot-unique oopDesc class. Any suggestions for producing a library that can be linked in such a manner?

**Edit:** Tried also linking to `libjava.so` at compile-time with no success.

Answer (score 0):

If the libjvm.so that you want to load is different than the libjvm.so that is implicitly linked by the java EXE, this is not going to work, because they will conflict unless you do something like this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228117/loading-multiple-shared-libraries-with-different-versions) or that [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629041/loading-two-different-versions-of-the-same-shared-library).  Is the java EXE loading the same libjvm.so that your library wants to reference?  You should be able to tell which .so is loaded by java EXE as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103443/how-to-check-what-shared-libraries-are-loaded-at-run-time-for-a-given-process).

If the java EXE and your library both want the same .so and it is still not working, I don't know what to say.

Comment: Thanks, I tested this, but it wasn't the issue. Still occurs even when linking to the exact same libraries.

Comment: This could be related?  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037962